Optimization problem involving the probabilities of two events
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and let $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$ be two $\textbf{independent}$ events in $\mathcal{F}$. Prove that:
$$
\max(P(A \cup B)^{c}, P(A \triangle B), P(A \cap B)) \geq \frac{4}{9},
$$
where $A \triangle B = (A - B) \cup (B - A)$ denotes the $\textbf{symmetric difference}$ of $A$ and $B$.
My Attempt Towards the Solution:
Let $P(A) = x$ and $P(B) = y$. We obtain the following simplifications:
$$
P(A \cap B) = xy,
$$
$$
P(A \triangle B) = x + y - 2xy,
$$
$$
P((A \cup B)^{c}) = 1 - x - y + xy.
$$
Another trivial observation is that these three probabilities are mutually exclusive and exhaustive events. However, I am unable to proceed beyond this. I suspect that the $\textbf{AM-GM inequality}$ could be useful, but I am unable to apply it concretely.
Any help or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

This should be a duplicate of this question except that question's only answer finishes with a graph and not with a rigorous demonstration. Once that's added this is a duplicate.
